# mysql queries run as root

Tags: mysql, root

My situation is like this:
I have two servers, one is a windows server running IIS and holds my web site.
The other is a linux server that holds my mysql server.

I created a (mysql) user on the mysql server with a minimum set of privileges, and I use its credentials when connecting from my website to run queries.

But when I run a query, and check the processes that are running on the mysql server (mysql> show processlist), I see that the query I executes (from the web site) is being run under the (mysql) root account!

Any idea why this should happen??

---

Hituptony got it :-)
My query was processed by a SP, and turned into a prepared statement and then run...
That SP was defined with the root account (god knows why), and more ever didn't have the "invoker" security clause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-programs-security.html

Comment: no, sorry I wasn't clear.
I meant that I ran "show processlist" from the mysql command line.
It shows(among other things) all the queries that are running now and who executed them.

Comment: is the query a stored proc or a SELECT ....??

Comment: A plain select. But one that can sometimes yield a pretty big result set.

Comment: Ha! my mistake! it's a plain select, but it is run through a stored procedure that prepares a statement! and that SP didn't have "SQL SECURITY INVOKER"! causing it to run under the definer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it would depend on what you are doing, if you are running a stored procedure and it is created by a root account, then when you run it it will still show the "user who created" it as the one running it, when in reality it is probably the connection user. In theory if you are running a select statement you would therein be running as the connection user, as there would be no "creator" to the select...if you catch my driftage...

Comment: thanks! my query was prepared via a SP, and it didn't have the "SQL SECURITY INVOKER" clause.